# Shortcut to go to changelist in commit dialog Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I wouldn't like to use mouse to review the changelist of commit dialog. I can get a focus to it by pushing <kbd>Tab</kbd> a lot of times. Do you know some more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open commit window:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

Then after commit window pops up: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: That's it! Shift+Tab take focus on changelist!

Comment: Then press a `Tab` key to move back to comment